# Export content of screen daemon to file

Tags: linux, arch-linux, gnu-screen

I'd like to export the content of a detached screen under linux.
I tried those command:

```
screen -x 2>&1 > temp
screen -x > temp 2>&1
screen -x > temp
```

But it's not working, It keeps reattaching to a session instead of exporting it in the "temp" file.

Screen version: 4.00.03jw4

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want to do something like:

```
screen -p 0 -X hardcopy
```

this generates a file `hardcopy.0` with the content of the screen session.
The argument to `-p` determines which session.

The files are dumped in screens current working directory or to the directory set set with the `hardcopydir` command. Check the screen configuration file for hardcopydir (`/etc/screenrc`).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer!
I can't find the hardcopy file.

Comment: it should be in the directory that you run the command in. Please check your write permissions there and post the version of `screen` you use (output of `screen -v` preferably in the question)

Comment: Screen version: 4.00.03jw4
I've got full r/w permission.

Comment: That is the same version I have, did you cut and paste the command? Run it in a different terminal than the running screen session. Any message from running the command?

Comment: yep, I used the same command.
But there is a program running in the screen, I don't know if this change anything or not?

Comment: The files are dumped in screens current working directory and can be set with the `hardcopydir` command. Check the screen configuration file for `hardcopydir` (`/etc/screenrc`). I recommend you start a new terminal, and another one with the same directory. Then start screen in one terminal and the command in the other, to make sure the file is generated once that works, find out where the other hardcopy.0 file was written (screen startup dir, screen current dir, dir defined by `hardcopydir` are all possibilities I would check.

Comment: That is perfect!
I just had to set `hardcopydir`!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're finding that the above doesn't seem to work, or it works and yet you can't seem to find the danged file, you can do this from inside the session itself:

`CTRL+A`

`CTRL+SHIFT+:`

`hardcopy -h /some/path/you/can/reach`

That should work and lets you put it wherever you want.